# WebView - wrong onLoadingChanged event

Tags: android, qt, webview, qml

I use QT 5.7 + QML + WebView + Android 6.0. I turn off internet on my phone, then try to load some url. At first webview status changed to LoadFailedStatus, but after 1 second it changed to LoadSucceededStatus. Why? There is no inthernet on device and error message still displayed on the screen.

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtWebView::initialize();
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtWebView 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: app
    visible: true

    WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: true
        url: "http://lenta.ru"

        onLoadingChanged: {
            if (loadRequest.status == WebView.LoadStartedStatus) {
                console.log("Load start: " + loadRequest.url)
            } else if (loadRequest.status == WebView.LoadSucceededStatus) {
                console.log("Load succeeded: " + loadRequest.url)
            } else if (loadRequest.status == WebView.LoadFailedStatus) {
                console.log("Load failed: " + loadRequest.url + ". Error code: " + loadRequest.errorString)   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
(onLoadingChanged): qml: Load start: https://lenta.ru/
(onLoadingChanged): qml: Load failed: https://lenta.ru/. Error code: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
(onLoadingChanged): qml: Load succeeded: https://lenta.ru/
(onLoadingChanged): qml: Load succeeded: https://lenta.ru/
```

Comment: You are requesting for URL.. and sometime internet connection fails before request complete. then this request added in Failure Queue. And when connection detect again then URL from that queue reload again

Comment: and second reason is may be. some website have some scripts like Google.com. that run inside Ajax control. so this script get called after some pause.

Comment: There is another reason. I turn off wi-fi and mobile internet, so there is no inthernet at all. And I don't turn it on. I get message "Load succeeded: https://lenta.ru/", but site not loaded.